# How to add a @tailwind CSS rule to CSS checker

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

[Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/what-is-tailwind) adds a `@tailwind` CSS *at* rule which is flagged as unknown.

How can I avoid this error?

For example, `styles.css`

`@tailwind preflight;`

`@tailwind utilities;`

Comment: Actually it seems this @ rule is only used by the tailwind tooling.

Comment: what about [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62254613/5212904)

Comment: Use only this line into your settings.json file of vs code       "scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"

Answer (score 407):

If you use Visual Studio Code, you can use the [PostCSS Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss) plugin.

Make sure you associate your `scss` files with PostCSS by adding the following to your `settings.json` file: `"files.associations": { "*.scss": "postcss" }`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with VueJS, Volar, and .vue files

Comment: For those like me who want to use this on `.scss` files (Angular app in my case), add this to your `settings.json`: `"files.associations": { "*.scss": "postcss" }`

Comment: While this got rid of the warning for me, it also disabled all intellisense for CSS. I can only assume I did something wrong or forgot a step, but hard to say what step could be forgotten when there is only 1...

Comment: @MagnusBull You did nothing wrong. The mentioned extension does not work well with IntelliSense. You could try using this one: `mhmadhamster.postcss-language` which has a little better IntelliSense support, but I think it does not integrate with the @tailwind directive. At least I didn't get it to work.

Comment: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5258#discussioncomment-1979394

This will be quicker solution.

Comment: it`s actually work with react project

Answer (score 283):

## 2022-05 Update

The official [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) extension now extends the built-in CSS language mode to fix these lint warnings, without losing any of VS Code’s default IntelliSense features.

Review the [Recommended VS Code Settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss#recommended-vs-code-settings) section to enable this for all CSS files in your workspace.

I leave my original answer intact below if you don’t want to install an additional extension, but since v0.8.0 it no longer conflicts with the built-in CSS support so that would be my recommended approach.

---

## Old Answer Without Extension

Visual Studio Code allows you to define [Custom Data for CSS Language Service](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/master/docs/customData.md).

For example, in your workspace’s `.vscode/settings.json` you can add:

```json
{
  "css.customData": [".vscode/css_custom_data.json"]
}
```

And then in `.vscode/css_custom_data.json` add:

```json
{
  "atDirectives": [
    {
      "name": "@tailwind",
      "description": "Use the @tailwind directive to insert Tailwind’s `base`, `components`, `utilities`, and `screens` styles into your CSS.",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind’s “Functions & Directives” documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives/#tailwind"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that you may have to reload the VS Code window for the change to be picked up.

Here is a copy of `.vscode/css_custom_data.json`, which contains all directives with short usage snippets (which in turn get syntax highlighted in vs code):

````json
{
  "version": 1.1,
  "atDirectives": [
    {
      "name": "@tailwind",
      "description": "Use the `@tailwind` directive to insert Tailwind's `base`, `components`, `utilities` and `screens` styles into your CSS.",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#tailwind"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "@responsive",
      "description": "You can generate responsive variants of your own classes by wrapping their definitions in the `@responsive` directive:\n```css\n@responsive {\n  .alert {\n    background-color: #E53E3E;\n  }\n}\n```\n",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#responsive"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "@screen",
      "description": "The `@screen` directive allows you to create media queries that reference your breakpoints by **name** instead of duplicating their values in your own CSS:\n```css\n@screen sm {\n  /* ... */\n}\n```\n…gets transformed into this:\n```css\n@media (min-width: 640px) {\n  /* ... */\n}\n```\n",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#screen"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "@variants",
      "description": "Generate `hover`, `focus`, `active` and other **variants** of your own utilities by wrapping their definitions in the `@variants` directive:\n```css\n@variants hover, focus {\n   .btn-brand {\n    background-color: #3182CE;\n  }\n}\n```\n",
      "references": [
        {
          "name": "Tailwind Documentation",
          "url": "https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#variants"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
````

Here's a preview of the result:

[image: preview of @screen directive]

The only directive missing is `@apply`, because it's declared at the CSS property level. The *CSS Language Service* probably doesn't expect `atRules` at the property level and won't pick up such directives.

Comment: > Note that you will have to reload the VS Code window for the change to be picked up. ~~~

It loaded instantly for me (VSCode 1.46.1 Win10). Thanks for all directives list.

Comment: This is a partial solution, unlike installing PostCSS Language Support suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801203/640208.

Comment: I truly prefer this solution rather than installing unnecessary packages.

Comment: I added a section for `@apply` and it worked for me. I did have to reload VS Code first.

Comment: @MagnusBull it seems to work for providing intellisense when you use it, but did you also get rid of your squiggles for the `unknownAtRules`? I get the documentation pop up as I use `@apply` but still continue to have the underlining error message.

Comment: @JosephBradshaw Yes, I was able to get rid of the yellow warning squiggles. I seem to remember it happening at the same time as I applied this config and reloaded VS Code: https://imgur.com/a/zhgEPko

Comment: Perfect answer: removes squiggly lines, retains IntelliSense and even adds additonall IntelliSense. Plus, I didn't need to reload VS Code.

Comment: Additionally to install the extension, you also need to set the "files.associations" setting as described under the "Recommended VS Code Settings" section here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss

Comment: In the __settings.json__ file, add `"files.associations": { "*.css": "tailwindcss" }` or you can use the __File: Associations__ settings GUI: 1. Click __Add Item__; 2. Enter `*.css` for _Item_ and `tailwindcss` for _Value_.

Comment: Could you edit this response to include this info^

Comment: The files.associations did not work for me, but I just changed the file type from CSS to tailwindcss with the button "CSS" in the status bar on the lower right.

Comment: I JUST installed (Nov 2022) the Tailwind plugin first, and still got the warning. The PostCSS plugin was still required for me /shrug, but I now see the filetype I should have switched to and that works too.

Comment: @ChrisZ I added a link to the recommended settings part of the extension documentation.

Comment: The "old" answer is still the better one. The Tailwind CSS Intellisense plugin when used with `"files.associations": { "*.css": "tailwindcss" }` breaks other linting rules in css files.

Comment: As mentioned in updated version, just to add if anyone using sass to add `"files.associations": { "*.scss": "tailwindcss" }` instead.

Answer (score 128):

This is the at-rule-no-unknown rule provided by Visual Studio Code's built-in list.

In order to get rid of it you need to do the following:

**1**. Install the Stylelint extension `code --install-extension stylelint.vscode-stylelint`

**2**. Install the Stylelint recommended configuration `npm install stylelint-config-recommended --save-dev`

**3**. Add these two lines in your Visual Studio Code USER SETTINGS

```
"css.validate": false, // Disable default CSS built-in lint
"stylelint.enable": true, // Enable Stylelint
"scss.validate": false, // Disable SCSS lint (optional if using scss)
```

**4**. Paste these lines into a file called `.stylelintrc` in your project's root directory; create it if it does not exist. More information about Stylelint's configuration follow this link: https://stylelint.io/user-guide/

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended",
  "rules": {
    "at-rule-no-unknown": [ true, {
      "ignoreAtRules": [
        "extends",
        "tailwind"
      ]
    }],
    "block-no-empty": null,
    "unit-allowed-list": ["em", "rem", "s"]
  }
}
```

Comment: The install is quite straight forward. It is exactly those 4 steps as shown.

Comment: I was able to hide the warning by only installing `stylelint` extension & disabling build-in `css`, `scss`, and `less` lint & enabling stylelint extension (No further steps).

Comment: @hasusuf Thanks, it works! But what is about `block-no-empty` and `unit-whitelist`? This is not needed here, right? Tailwind itself has `px` units, so I don't understand why they are not whitelisted here. Is this just personal preference?

Comment: @RamboNo5 The configuration is relevant to the [stylelint-config-recommended](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-recommended#extending-the-config)

Comment: shinnn.stylelint extension has been deleted so this is irrelevant now.

Comment: Step 3 works for me. No need for step 4. Thank you!

Comment: Not working for me, and only shows more errors on my very simple css rule ```.button {
  @apply p-1;
}```

Comment: 'unit-whitelist' has been deprecated. Instead use 'unit-allowed-list'. See: https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/13.7.0/lib/rules/unit-whitelist/README.md

Comment: If you are using Vuejs and Vetur, make sure to use “vetur.

Comment: If using Vue and Vetur, and you want to switch off the css validation within the <style> tags of .vue files, then you need to use the setting "vetur.validation.style": false.

Comment: I found that I had to `npm install --save-dev stylelint` as well, or the Stylelint extension won't do anything unless you have it installed globally. (You can test if it's working by typing `color: #12;`.) The `"block-no-empty"` and `"unit-allow-list"` rules don't need to be changed (they're unrelated), and Tailwind doesn't add an `@extends` rule, so you should be able to do this: `"at-rule-no-unknown": [ true, { "ignoreAtRules": ["tailwind"] } ]`

Comment: The link is broken: *"Page Not Found. We could not find what you were looking for. Please contact the owner of the site that linked you to the original URL and let them know their link is broken."*

Answer (score 51):

#### Currently Recommended Visual Studio Code Settings (Updated 2022-12-15)

**Official Tailwind CSS IntelliSense Visual Studio Code Documentation**

Use the *files.associations* setting to tell Visual Studio Code to always open .css files in Tailwind CSS mode:

```json
    "files.associations": {
      "*.css": "tailwindcss"
    }
```

Tip: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> from Visual Studio Code to open Settings; then, type *"Files Associations"*.

By default Visual Studio Code will not trigger completions when editing "string" content, for example within JSX attribute values. Updating the *editor.quickSuggestions* setting may improve your experience:

```json
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "strings": true
    }
```

Combining both, your *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file (if new) will look similar to this:

```json
    {
        "files.associations": {
          "*.css": "tailwindcss"
        },
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": true
        }
    }
```

Source: *[Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss)*

---

#### Previously Recommended Visual Studio Code Settings (Deprecated)

Visual Studio Code has built-in CSS validation which may display errors when using Tailwind CSS-specific syntax, such as @apply. You can disable this with the *css.validate* setting:

```
"css.validate": false
```

The "editor.quickSuggestions" setting recommendation remains the same then and now. Combining both, your *settings.json* file (if new) would look similar to this:

```
{
    "css.validate": false,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
      }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer, not ignoring CSS> Lint:Unknown At Rules within VS Code, cheers Jorge!

Answer (score 49):

**1.** Just go to settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for a shortcut).

**2.** Search for CSS in the search bar.

**3.** look for the *"CSS > Lint: Unknown At Rules"*

**4.** Select "ignore" from the dropdown options.

This ignores the warning. If you're OK with it.

Comment: The question is how to ADD tailwind support. Ignoring it and skipping the syntax awareness is a terrible answer.

Comment: this is a great and simple answer! it does not require installing dangerous plugins to solve a simple issue. thanks!

Comment: @checklist this is a horrible answer. It ignores the problem instead of solving it. There is a reason why this rule exists, it is to prevent from typing unknown at rules... by disabling it you are removing that safeguard.

Comment: It's a great answer as it specifically states that it ignores the warning. It's up to developer to take the risk. RTFM

Comment: switching to using tailwindcss for file associations is a much better approach since it actually fixes this specific issue rather than ignoring all warnings.

Comment: @NickLothian "Tailwind CSS IntelliSense" will work anyway. Ignoring the "Unknown At Rules" just silencing the ESLint.

Answer (score 31):

I am new here but the simplest answer to solve this is to follow these steps:

1. Open the CSS file where you import Tailwind CSS
2. Press Ctrl + Shift + P and search for “change language mode”
3. Inside the search bar, type “tailwindcss” and select it.
4. Now your CSS file is associated with Tailwind CSS instead of regular css and the warnings should be gone.

Credit to : https://batchnepal.com/topic/fix-unknown-at-rule-warning-in-vscode

In this way you won't need to install any third plugins or ignore any error. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I found the same page and it was the best approach and you don't need to do anything else editing files.

Comment: For me this is the best answer

Comment: This does not work for files that have mixed languages, like any regular component of a modern framework.

Comment: I had to install the tailwind.css VSCode extension, as when I tried this without that, the option of Tailwind wasn't in the drop down. Now it is, and it works.

Answer (score 29):

My recommendation is to install [PostCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostCSS) language support and then rename `tailwind.css` to `tailwind.pcss`. Then change the references in your `package.json` scripts (or whatever build scripts you are using for tailwind) to `tailwind.pcss` from `tailwind.css` and everything should work fine.

The *@apply* rule is compatible with postCSS: *[Does @apply in Tailwind conflict with @apply in postcss-cssnext? #325](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/325)*

Comment: The PostCSS language support extension now binds to .css files too, so no need to change the extension

Comment: I did something similar to this calling the files `filename.pcss.css` to keep some trace of what is css vs postcss.

Answer (score 21):

According to the *tailwindcss-intellisense* GitHub repository:

#### Recommended Visual Studio Code Settings

##### `files.associations`

Use the `files.associations` setting to tell Visual Studio Code to always open `.css` files in Tailwind CSS mode:

```json
"files.associations": {
   "*.css": "tailwindcss"
}
```

It fixed the *@tailwind* warning and added Tailwind CSS directives, functions to intellisense.

More information about the Tailwind CSS intellisense extension can be found in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense).

Answer (score 15):

> **SCSS**

If you are using Sass with Tailwind CSS, you will still see errors in your `.scss` files using these earlier answers to this question.

To properly lint Sass, you can add to your Visual Studio Code settings:

```
"scss.validate": false,
```

Follow [the instructions by hasusuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607602/how-to-add-a-tailwind-css-rule-to-css-checker/48165524#48165524), but turn off the default Visual Studio Code validator:

Add these three settings:

```
"css.validate": false,
"scss.validate": false,
"stylelint.enable": true,
```

Answer (score 14):

Just add three lines into the *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file:

```
"css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore",
"css.validate": true,
"scss.validate": true,
```

Comment: This worked for me. Plain and simple. Thanks. (VS version 1.52.1)

Comment: This doesn't "work" ...it just turns all the intelligence off. Ugh!

Comment: it worked for me adding only this
"scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore",

notice the s before scss. since thats what i am using! thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I edited my `.vscode/settings.json` file by adding in `"css.validate": false`, seemed to work for me without installing external libraries.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14999#issuecomment-258635188

Answer (score 6):

After many tests:

The PostCSS and STYLUS syntax highlighter remove warnings, but CSS Intellisence is incomplete. It does not show the first-utitilies classes Tailwind.

I installed '**language-stylus**' plugin, in Visual Studio Code.

Settings> User setting:

```
"files.associations": {
   "* .css": "stylus"
 },
```

[CSS Intellisence is incomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/burPr.jpg)

Comment: "utitilies" looks like [a misspelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/utilities#Noun).

Comment: OK, we will [never know](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients). The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 1 year ago "*

Answer (score 6):

This works for me when dealing with CSS and SCSS. In your *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file, add/edit the code below.

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.css": "tailwindcss",
    "*.scss": "tailwindcss"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are your Tailwind rules inside a .scss file (or others stylesheet) files?

Please follow the Tailwind documentation and put the rules inside a `.css` (not scss or others).

1. Rules are correctly detected?

   - No, go back to Tailwind documentation
   - Yes
2. Do you need to include it in a sccs file or other?
   Then do the following:

   - In `style.scss`, remove all Tailwind CSS rules and add the line:

     ```
     @import "<path_to_my_tailwind_conf>";
     ```
   - `<my_tailwind_conf>.css`:

     ```
     @tailwind base;
     @tailwind components;
     @tailwind utilities;
     ```

Replace the string inside the angle bracket, <>, with your filename and filepath.

Comment: Questions do not belong in answers, even if rhetorical. [Stack Overflow is ***not*** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score 3):

Add [this Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) to add the language support.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to install PostCSS language support, an extension found in Visual Studio Code. That will remove the error that is displaying.

The *@apply* rule is compatible with PostCSS: *[Does @apply in Tailwind conflict with @apply in postcss-cssnext? #325](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/325)*

VS Marketplace: *[PostCSS Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss)*

**Note:** uninstall PostCSS intellisense and highlighting extension from Visual Studio Code. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: adding PostCSS Language Support instantly fixed it for me. I don't have the other 2 plugins. I didn't even need to reload VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

Today Visual Studio Code is configurable. To get rid of this warning in your Visual Studio Code, you can create a folder named ".vscode"
and create a new file called "settings.json".
In the *settings.json* file you can paste this JSON content:

```html
{
  "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
}
```

[image]

Comment: This gets rid of ALL warnings; not a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio Code, open user settings by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.

Search for **Unknown At Rules**.

Change Lint from **warning** to **ignore**.

Comment: Besides lots of folk already suggesting this, ignoring an issue does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding for future reference

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: This seems highly unlikely to make a difference. Any more explanation here?

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of responses to tell you to "ignore" the error in configuration files. For me, it's a bad idea and not a response.

To fix that, I use `import` from "basic CSS" like this:

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You most do is to add to setting.json on VScode

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.css": "tailwindcss"
}
```

**2.** and this will solve your problem with index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Source Information:** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss

Comment: How is this different from the existing Answers?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add these into. Click menu *File* → *Preferences* → *settings.json*

> ```
> "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore",
> "css.validate": true,
> "scss.validate": true,
> ```

Add this code to *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)*.

Comment: Removing the error message is not a solution, now if I make a typo and write "@layre" it won't show up at the linting step.

Answer (score 0):

we can remove this error by installing the extension **PostCSS Language Support** from the [extensions search panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93h7t.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34861760)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and after some troubleshooting, I found a solution that worked for me. If you're facing issues with the `@tailwind` CSS rule not being recognized by the CSS checker, follow these instructions:

1. Go to `settings` ( Ctrl + , for a shortcut).
2. Search for **CSS** in the search bar.
3. Look for the "`CSS > Lint: Unknown At Rules`".
4. Select "`ignore`" from the dropdown options.

[image: Reference image]

This should resolve the issue, and the CSS checker should recognize the `@tailwind` rule without any problems. Remember to save your changes and restart your development server or IDE for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you using VS Code. Find PostCSS Language Support in the extensions marketplace and install it. That may help you.

Answer (score -1):

If the Tailwind CSS is not working as well as the error caused by the unknown rule, you need to build it again. For example, if you have been running `npm run dev` in a local environment, you can exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and run `npm run dev` again to create a normal pure CSS file, which will enable tailwind CSS to work.

This is exactly the problem I was stuck with and how I was able to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) for shortcut.

Open the settings and search for “unknown”. The first result should be the one you’re looking for: *CSS > Lint*: Unknown At Rules:

Change that to *ignore:*

Done!

Still don’t understand? Follow the pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This plagiarises at least one previous answer, [fahad saleem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607602/how-to-add-a-tailwind-css-rule-to-css-checker/64211089#64211089).