# How to ignore an false error in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

For a new project I am going to use tailwind.css with sass in visual studio code. Tailwind provides a @apply function to mix the contents of existing tailwind classes to my custom scss.

So I can do sth like this:

```
.btn {
  @apply .font-bold .py-2 .px-4 .rounded;
}
```

The compiled css file will then automatically have tailwinds rules for these settings. However this causes error notifications in the pure scss file of course. To be consistent among my code I am planning to solve as much as I can with the apply rule, which will result in many "false" errors.

Is there a way to solve this, for example that IntelliSense will accept the @apply rule in my scss files?

Comment: nvm, dupliacted post. Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48165524/5991491

Answer (score 0):

When you are using tailwindCSS just declaring a style is not enough to apply the style effectively in your app. Since you are declaring your style in an input.css you have to add a layer to the global file that contains every tailwindCSS styles (output file). I would recommand you to do this instead :

```js
@layer components {
  .btn {
    @apply .font-bold .py-2 .px-4 .rounded;
  }
}
```