# How do you get rid of these SASS linting errors when using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, prettier, tailwind-css

[image: Linting error]

I'm using Tailwind in a [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) project.  My environment is Visual Studio Code, using the [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) code formatter.

How do I get rid of these linting error alerts?

Comment: What's the error? [This](https://www.meidev.co/blog/visual-studio-code-css-linting-with-tailwind/) might help

Comment: **stylelint** from **shinnosuke watanabe** is no longer available on vscode extensions.

Comment: @Digvijay after a bit of digging all i can find is ...edit your settings.json file (you can do it per project by putting this file in you project root) `.vscode/settings.json`.  Then put in `{  "scss.validate": false}` you also lose all other error detection. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607602/how-to-add-a-tailwind-css-rule-to-css-checker#answer-61333686) answer gets rid of error highlighting on some of tailwinds directives, but not all, and not class names that are listed one after another like I do after using @apply.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### Solution for both .css and .scss

1. At the root level of your project, update or create a directory, *.vscode*, with a file, *settings.json*:

   [image]
2. Add the following to file *.vscode/settings.json*:

   ```
   {
     "css.validate": false,
     "less.validate": false,
     "scss.validate": false
   }
   ```
3. Install the [vscode-stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint) extension

   [image]
4. Install [stylelint-config-standard](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard#readme):

   `npm i stylelint-config-standard -D`
5. Create a `stylelint.config.js` file at the root level and add:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     extends: ['stylelint-config-recommended'],
     rules: {
       "at-rule-no-unknown": [
         true,
         {
           ignoreAtRules: [
             "tailwind",
             "apply",
             "variants",
             "responsive",
             "screen",
           ],
         },
       ],
       "declaration-block-trailing-semicolon": null,
       "no-descending-specificity": null,
     },
   };
   ```
6. Restart Visual Studio Code

##### Results:

You get rid of these [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) linting errors when using Tailwind CSS and keep doing CSS validation with [Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/).

[image]

Comment: Great!  This works fabulously for me.  I added "extend" to the ignoreAtRules array.  I added a polyfill for '.container' because when using tailwind in SCSS doesn't allow you to @apply some responsive classes.  Please correct me if I'm doing this wrong.  Once again though, thanks for this!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can modify the `stylelint.config.js` file [rules](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list) as you see fit. Here is an [example](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard#extending-the-config) with `extend` as you mentioned. From the example, just notice that without `ignoreAtRules["tailwind"...]` you will get `Unexpected unknown at-rule "@tailwind"` when configuring Tailwind, e.g. `@tailwind base;`

Comment: why does this happen? is it a bug with vscode?

Answer (score 9):

You can tell Visual Studio Code's CSS linter to ignore "Unknown At Rules" (like `@tailwind`).  This will leave the rest of your CSS validation intact:

1. Visual Studio Code → Command Palette (e.g., menu *View* → *Command Palette*)* → *Workspace Settings* → Search for: *CSS Unknown At Rules*
2. Set to `ignore`

[image]

Visual Studio Code can also whitelist specific CSS properties with *"CSS > Lint: Valid Properties"*, but it doesn't look like whitelisting specific 'at rules' is supported yet.

Comment: This is actually the best solution, because turning off the whole scss linting is not a good idea,.

Answer (score 3):

#### Quick solution for both .css and .scss (*not recommended*)

1. At the root level of your project, update or create a directory, *.vscode*, with a file, *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)*:

   [image]
2. Add the following to file *.vscode/settings.json*:

   ```
   {
     "css.validate": false
   }
   ```

   [image]

#### Results:

You get rid of these SASS linting errors when using Tailwind CSS, but you disable CSS validation.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The other answers are thermonuclear. Even [Confucius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucius) stopped with a canon...

This is the one that did it for me.

To reproduce: *Settings* → search for "invalid Tailwind directive", and update the value for this rule to "ignore". voilà.

Comment: Edit: I found a solution to my issue here: https://www.codeconcisely.com/posts/tailwind-css-unknown-at-rules/

I don't see Tailwind CSS in my settings. Are you using Taliwind CSS extension? 
I am getting `Unknown at rule @tailwind` error in VS Code in my Next.js project installed with @latest together with TS, EsLint and `Tailwind`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this one-line fix in VSCode's settings.json

```
"scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
```

This way you don't have to disable CSS validation.

Answer (score 0):

My case was a bit different, but I guess it may help. I was getting a below error in my Next.js setup with Tailwind:

`Unknown at rule @tailwind`

in global.css including only initial Tailwind setup:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Some of the solutions provided here were adding extra complexity which in the end didn't help solve the problem.

What worked for me was associating the file with Tailwind CSS by installing Tailwind CSS IntelliSense Plugin for VS Code and than changing language mode for the file.

I provide an article that help me solve the problem: https://www.codeconcisely.com/posts/tailwind-css-unknown-at-rules/#installing-tailwind-css-intellisense-plugin

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Visual Studio Code then you can add support for modern and experimental CSS within Visual Studio Code by installing the plugin *[PostCSS Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss)* to fix the error while using Tailwind CSS directives.