# Unknown at rule @tailwind css(unknownAtRules)

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

So this is my first time using Typescript and Tailwind. I already followed tailwind guide for create-react-app but when I try to run `npm start` I got this error:

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

this is my `index.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components; 
@tailwind utilities;

body {...
```

I got warning in index.css `Unknown at rule @tailwind css(unknownAtRules)`

and this is my `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
// import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div className="px-4 py-2 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg hover:bg-green-700">tombol</div>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a @tailwind CSS rule to css checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607602/how-to-add-a-tailwind-css-rule-to-css-checker)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is strange. Try to update your Node.js to the latest current stable version and try again.

Answer (score 22):

Create or edit `.vscode/settings.json` and add:

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.css": "tailwindcss"
  }
}
```

Additionally the VSCode [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) is helpful - these notes are from their docs.

Comment: This the answer that worked best for me. The "PostCSS Language Support" extension also fixes it, but is slow and breaks another CSS extension I use regularly (Color Info). And I just use a different PostCSS extension for Intellisense.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, without the VSCode plugin and just the `settings.json` the `tailwind.css` is seen as a plaintext file with no color highlighting or completions. Plugin installed, everything fine.

Answer (score 4):

Update NodeJS using `nvm` by following the steps from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows

Make sure you have uninstalled the previous node_modules folder from your project.

Follow these steps

Install RimRaf: 
`npm install rimraf -g`

And in the project folder delete the node_modules folder with: 
`rimraf node_modules`

Reference: [How to Delete node_modules - Deep Nested Folder in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175200/how-to-delete-node-modules-deep-nested-folder-in-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Add VS Code extension postcss language support

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add file `.postcssrc` into root of your project with content:

```json
{
  "plugins": {
    "tailwindcss": {}
  }
}
```

and `tailwind.config.js` with content:

```json
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```