# Unknown at rule @tailwind CSS in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, react-dom

[image]

cant able to resolve this error while compiling the code ..! In fact I've tried many other ways of implementation

//Index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Does this post answer your question? [How to add a @tailwind CSS rule to css checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607602/how-to-add-a-tailwind-css-rule-to-css-checker)  If not, can you please specify how the questions are different/distinct to help visitors understand how best to assist you?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Make sure to install PostCSS Language Support, extension found in the VSCODE.
That will remove the error that is displaying.

@apply rule is compatible with postCSS: https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/325

VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss