# How to configure TailwindCSS with a Deno Vite project?

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, deno

I have initialized a new deno vite app and am trying to configure tailwindcss.

The first thing I did was add tailwindcss and postcss to my import_map.json and cache them:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "tailwindcss": "npm:tailwindcss@^3.2",
    "postcss": "npm:postcss@^8.4"
  }
}
```

I then generated a tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js with the `npx tailwindcss init -p` command.

Lastly, I added the @tailwind rules to my index.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

At this point, I'm actually getting the lint error `Unknown at rule @tailwindcss(unknownAtRules)` in my index.css file even though I have the [tailwindcss vs code extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607602/how-to-add-a-tailwind-css-rule-to-css-checker) installed.

When I run my project with `deno task dev` I get the "Hello World" text showing up but my tailwindcss classes do not take effect, here is my App.jsx file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-red-500 rounded-lg shadow-xl min-h-[50px]">
      <p className="text-white">Hello World</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Note: I had to delete the postcss.config.js file in order to even run the app.

Are there any other steps I need to take to get tailwindcss working or is it just not compatible at this time?

Answer (score 1):

It seems TailwindCSS doesn't support Deno, see GitHub disscussion: [Tailwind CSS support Deno](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2971)

eg. running `deno run -A npm:tailwindcss init` fails immediately:

```
Uncaught TypeError: acorn.Parser.extend(...).extend is not a function
```

Alternatively I tried to use [Windi CSS](https://github.com/windicss/vite-plugin-windicss), but unfortunately the Vite plugin didn't work:

```
vite:c15:27:24 [vite] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123), stat 'C:\project\!C:\project\node_modules'
```